# Spark task count vs pushdown filters

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

our spark setup has several problems already but i'm curious what can be done about this

We have around 60k parquet files and a heavy filter that gets rid of lots of records via pushdown filter. But we still end up having roughly 60k tasks / partitions when we process the files

Is there something that we can do about this scenario?

I came across openCostInBytes e.t.c but unable to get the result i.e. reduction in task / partition count

Comment: What is the size of each file? Did you try merge small files to larger sizes? What version of Spark are u using? Have you tried setting spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes to bigger sizes may be 256 or 512 MB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532937/how-spark-get-number-of-tasks-reading-parquet-files/61595640#61595640  Not convinced anything is odd.